# UML - How to depict an application based on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, uml, diagram, deployment-diagram

Given a microservice application deployed in k8s cluster, I need to reflect it's structure on a UML deployment diagram.

In my case, the deployment diagram has to display:

1. Physical devices, nodes and their high-level network relation
2. High-level components/packages relation to nodes

Technically, it's the k8s deployed on a cluster of nodes, and my application is upon it. The concrete microservice container is not guaranteed to be placed on a concrete node, which makes it unclear how to relate UML components to the cluster of nodes.

Possible options I think of (none of them sound good):

- Split the diagram into two views: physical infrastructure view and deployment view. *This solves potential diagram overwhelming*.
- Create an "abstraction layer" block (component/package), representing a `<<pod environment>>`. The physical nodes could be related to this "abstraction layer" with aggregation -<> arrow; the microservice components are contained within the latter. *This overwhelms and confuses the diagram a lot*.
- Do not depict individual pods, only show the k8s cluster physical nodes (worst option)

The best outcome is a single diagram without excessive elements (like kubernetes components, -- ingress, services, configmaps, ..., which obviously exist in any k8s deployment), showing physical nodes and the related application components.

Comment: You answered your own question, didn't you?

Comment: No, I didn't. None of options I assume fully fit the best outcome. And no guarantees there is no such. Did you?

Comment: In most cases: there is no silver bullet. And you have to make compromises.

Comment: Thanks for a minute of philosophy, the point of my question is to ensure there is no such silver bullet, or perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, it wasn't meant ironically. Christophe's answer is more or less pointing towards the same directions you already found. Many ways lead to Rome. And (since the referred answer was closed as being opinion based) most people here agree that you have choices.